# How to search and get substring on php page?

Tags: php

I tried extracting a substring from a text on my php page using preg_match_all
If the string is:

```
"Your customer ID is (CUS12345). Please login below." 
preg_match_all('/\b(CUS\d+/', $text, $matches);
```

This doesnt work. I would like some suggestions on how to extract only the customer id - CUS12345 from it using php.

Comment: To start with, you have an unbalanced group.

Answer (score 1):

- You had an unbalanced group.
- Word boundaries (`\b`) doesn't match spaces.

Try this:

```
\((CUS\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aS1zR4/1

This would make your PHP become

```
$string = "Your customer ID is (CUS12345). Please login below.";
preg_match("/\((CUS\d+)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); //$matches[1] holds what you captured: CUS12345
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked, irrespective of no of characters. Thanks all for your hlp

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. Please [accept as an answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) to notify others that your question has  been solved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
"Your customer ID is (CUS12345). Please login below." 
preg_match_all('/CUS\d{5,}/', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: This won't work for 2 reasons. You have no delimiters, and you're searching from the start of a string to the end of the string. `CUS12345` isn't the only thing in the string. Further, what if it's `CUS123456`?

Comment: Edited. Forgot to paste in the delimiters and I edited it so it will match at least 5 or more digits

Comment: Ok, now what if It's `CUS1234`? Granted OP only gave 1 example of a string he'd like caught, but if it's not thought about, it can cause some serious issues. You also have `^` and `$` in your regular expression which will start looking from the start to the end of `$text` - in this case, won't capture anything.

Comment: I assumed from what he said each id would be 5 digits based on his example

Comment: Ah my bad, I was testing it just on the phrase not from a whole text. Fixed